# Outlook Add-In SSO access token missing email claim

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am creating an outlook add-in and am trying to use the SSO access token as authorisation for my backend.

I have the flow working. I trigger my Add-In, get the access token and use the access token to "login" to my backend.

However, the issue I have is that I am not getting the email claim in the token despite a) adding it to the API permissions in the Azure App Registration, b) adding to the WebApplicationInfo. Should I be receiving it?

Azure App Registration Permissions

[image: Azure App Registration]

Web Application Info

```
<WebApplicationInfo>
    <Id>xxx</Id>
    <Resource>api://localhost:3000/xxx</Resource>
    <Scopes>
        <Scope>openid</Scope>
        <Scope>User.Read</Scope>
        <Scope>profile</Scope>
        <Scope>email</Scope>
    </Scopes>
</WebApplicationInfo>
```

Code to receive token

`OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken( { allowSignInPrompt: true })`

Token received

```
{
  "aud": "api://localhost:3000/xxx",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/my_tenant_id/",
  "iat": 1605992211,
  "nbf": 1605992211,
  "exp": 1605999711,
  "acr": "1",
  "aio": "E2RgYDDdzii4P/xP/cPTbg4lPk7dJ6c8aQnapLU19aiV+Zy400sA",
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ],
  "appid": "xxx",
  "appidacr": "0",
  "family_name": "Adams",
  "given_name": "Iain",
  "ipaddr": "51.111.111.111",
  "name": "Iain Adams",
  "oid": "my_oid",
  "pwd_exp": "157262",
  "pwd_url": "https://portal.microsoftonline.com/ChangePassword.aspx",
  "rh": "0.AAAAmj9NLsNP80SAITLYeWEJg9YOWdOzUgJBrv-q0ikqsBxHANs.",
  "scp": "access_as_user",
  "sub": "my_sub",
  "tid": "my_tenant",
  "unique_name": "iain@abc.com",
  "upn": "iain@abc.com",
  "uti": "1KNbNttkDUCrKXblaK5BAA",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

Whilst I know the email address is being returned in the upn and unique_name claims, AND, I know that oid should be used as the unique identifier for this user, however, I need to lookup based on email address (if it exists).

Comment: The "Email" value is part of optional claims. It's included by default if the user is a guest in the tenant. For managed users (it means, the users inside the tenant), it must be requested through this optional claim or, on v2.0 only, with the OpenID scope. For managed users, the email address must be set in the Office admin portal (https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home#/users)

Comment: Do you have a chance to research my answer? is that helping you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to customize the access token configuration and then add the **email** as an optional claim. Go to **azure portal>App registrations>your app>Token configuration**.

[image]

Parse the token:

[image]

You need to pay attention to: **For managed users (the users inside the tenant), it must be requested through this optional claim or, on v2.0 only, with the OpenID scope.**

See: [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#v10-and-v20-optional-claims-set).

Answer (score 0):

The "Email" value is part of [optional claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#v10-and-v20-optional-claims-set). It's included by default if the user is a guest in the tenant. For managed users (it means, the users inside the tenant), it must be requested through this optional claim or, on v2.0 only, with the OpenID scope. For managed users, the email address must be set in the Office admin portal (https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home#/users).